# Traffic_Conflict_Prediction

Tags: python, conflict, traffic

I am trying to find out the traffic confilct. My code is:
I am trying to find out the traffic confilct. My code is:

```
import os
import math
fileset=os.listdir('C:\Users\Tawkir\Desktop\Lab Work')
for file in fileset:
    num=file.split('.')[0].split('-')[0]
    filename=r'C:\Users\Tawkir\Desktop\Lab Work +file'
    data=pd.read_csv(filename)
    data=data.loc[data['lane_id']<10]
    a=(data.groupby(['track_id'])['lane_id'].max()-data.groupby(['track_id'])['lane_id'].min()).reset_index().rename(columns={'lane_id':'delta'})
    b=data.groupby(['track_id'])['lane_id'].max().astype(int).reset_index().rename(columns={'lane_id':'new'})
    c=data.groupby(['track_id']).lane_id.nth(0).reset_index().rename(columns={'lane_id':'first'})
    d=data.groupby(['track_id']).lane_id.nth(-1).reset_index().rename(columns={'lane_id':'last'})
    data=pd.merge(data,a)
    del(a)
    data=pd.merge(data,b)
    del(b)
    data=pd.merge(data,c)
    del(c)
    data=pd.merge(data,d)
    del(d)
    data.loc[(data['delta']==0.5)&(data['first']!=data['first'].astype(int))&(data['last']!=data['last'].astype(int)),
    'lane_id']=data.loc[(data['delta']==0.5)&(data['first']!=data['first'].astype(int))&(data['last']!=data['last'].astype(int)),'new']
    data=data.iloc[:,0:13]
    data['speed']=data['speed']/3.6
    excel_file='./data_geo/'+num+'_geo.xlsx'
    map_data=pd.read_excel(excel_file)
    a2=-0.1301
    ttc_data=ttc(data,map_data,a2)
    ttc_data=ttc_data.sort_values(by=['track_id1','track_id2','ttc'])
    ttc_data.to_csv("ttc_data3.csv", index=False)
    ttc_data.drop_duplicates(subset=['track_id1','track_id2'],inplace=True)
    ttc_data.to_csv("ttc_data2.csv", index=False)
    ttc_data=ttc_data.loc[ttc_data['ttc']<=20]
    ttc_data.to_csv("ttc_data.csv",index=False)
    del(ttc_data)
    del(data)
```

Plese help me to solve the issue.
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

Comment: There are hundreds of questions about that error message. What research have you done to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line 3 to below line

```
fileset=os.listdir(r'C:\Users\Tawkir\Desktop\Lab Work')
```

we added prefix with r to say python it is a raw string